# upper to lower and vice-versa without loop in C++?

Tags: c++, toggle, toupper, tolower

Input:

```
abcdE
```

Output:

```
ABCDe
```

I am looking for an efficient and less code solution for this code:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int len, ;
    string data;

    cin >> data;

    len = data.length();

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (isupper(data[i]))
            data[i] = tolower(data[i]);
        else
            data[i] = toupper(data[i]);

    cout << data << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there is: [`std::ctype::toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/toupper), you may apply that using a `std::transform()` algo or such.

Comment: You might be able to write this in fewer lines but as for efficient this is O(N) and since you have to visit every element that as good as you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::string str("abcdE");
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char c) {
        return isupper(c) ? tolower(c) : toupper(c);
});
```

Comment: thats effectively a loop, but worse since instead of performing a cached block of code the way cpus are optimized, it performs an anonymous function call on every single character. It's like a loop but instead of doing X, you are calling a function on each iteration that does X. It also loses compatibility with older c++ versions. Quite a hefty price for cleverness.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) from `algorithm` library.

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string data = "AbcDEf";
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [](char& x){std::islower(x) ? x = std::toupper(x) : x = std::tolower(x);});
    std::cout << data<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use magic numbers for characters.  C++ has the syntax to let you use the characters instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver I suppose this makes you happy now.

Comment: No but I will remove the down vote.  AFAIK this is still a broken way to do it.

Comment: And why do you feel so?

Comment: There are other character sets besides ASCII than can be used for C++ and the letter blocks do not need to be contiguous.  Only the number block is guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: Agreed. Better to use the inbuilt functions.